# Get Data between two months with different years in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I got a table in sql server which has several fields including expYear in int, expMonth in int.

I am writing a SP to retrieve data between two months. which i can do by  `(expMonth between @M1 and @M2) AND @currentYear=expYear`  if both M1 and M2 in the same `expYear`.

But `if my M1=11(december)` which is in the year 2016 `and M2=2(february)` which is in the year 2017 then it doesn't work.

Could anyone tell what to do? Please remember, in DB both `"expYear "` and `"expMonth "` value are stored as int. even `"@M1"`, `"@M2"`, `"@currentYear"` all are coming from back end as int.

Comment: why don't you use the full date in the comparison?

Comment: l don't have full date in the DB. The two fields "expYear " and "expMonth " both are int and i have to calculate "which cards are expiring in next two months."

Comment: Shouldn't you have two year parameters then ?

Comment: yes from back end i can send one parameter which is current year and one more parameter nextExpYear if the current month is 11 or 12

Comment: You should reconsider your database structure. If possible, keep the dates in a date column.

Comment: so if you dont care about years, you can use the built in funcion "datepart" where you can take only the month,  `datepart(month,yourdate)=month`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build proper dates from your columns and input and compare them like this:

```
SELECT <ColumnsList>
FROM <TableName>
WHERE   CAST(RIGHT('0000' + CAST(expYear as varchar(4)), 4) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(expMonth as varchar(2)), 2) +'-01' As Date)
        BETWEEN CAST(RIGHT('0000' + CAST(@currentYear as varchar(4)), 4) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@M1  as varchar(2)), 2) +'-01' As Date)
        AND CAST(RIGHT('0000' + CAST(@currentYear as varchar(4)), 4) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@M2 as varchar(2)), 2) +'-01' As Date)
```

Comment: Thank you all for the effort. i just use this one  and it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing but arithmetic

```
declare @m1 int =11, @m2 int =1, @y1 int =2015, @y2 int=2016
select * 
from (
    values (2015,9),(2015,10),(2015,11),(2015,12),(2016,1),(2016,2),(2016,3),(2016,4)
    ) t(y,m)
where 100*y+m between 100*@y1+@m1 and 100*@y2+@m2
```

Comment: Better then my answer.

Comment: Dear @Serg, could u please explain little bit the answer u give. i would be very happy to learn something new.

Comment: No problem, just ask what exactly is the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the two columns and convert them to `datetime`. After that, you can use the `BETWEEN` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because SQL does not know that your M1 and M2 are repressing months. For it these are merely integer values. It cannot determine that if the first value < second value then it has to navigate to the next year. It will only search for all values that lie between M1 and M2 for the year provided. It will first get the rows for which M1 and M2 values lie between the range provided and then further refine it to the rows which have the specified year. So according to your example it will get the rows year 2016 only whose M1 and M2 value lie between 11 and 2.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your SP simply querying data, or is it doing an action on any of your data sources? If it's simply querying, then my suggestion would be to add a simple intermediary step to your SP that places your data into a temp table and creates a new variable that concatenates the month and year. So it might look something like this:

```
Select *,
ExpMonth + "-" + ExpYear AS ExpDate
Into #temp  
From [table]
```

Then, when you set your parameters for your stored procedure, you can query from #temp and  set your parameters to look for data between two ExpDates (11-2016 and 2-2017).

Answer (score 0):

If @M1 is 11 and @M2 is 2 how do you know that the year corresponding to @M1 is 2015 and not 2014 or 2013? Neither does SQL Server know what you mean, you just compare an integer to be >= 11 and <= 2. There is no value that meets that condition.

You will need to pass the year and month for each from and to date, something like this:

```
DECLARE @FROM INT = 201511
DECLARE @TO INT = 201602

SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE expYear * 100 + expMonth BETWEEN @FROM AND @TO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try reworking something like this:

```
if @M1 > @M2
  ... (@currentYear*12+@M1) <= (expYear*12+expMonth) AND (expYear*12+expMonth) <= ((@currentYear+1)*12+@M2) ...
else
  ... (@currentYear*12+@M1) <= (expYear*12+expMonth) AND (expYear*12+expMonth) <= (@currentYear*12+@M2) ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to start by defining two "year" variables called @startYear (or @Y1) and @endYear (or @Y2), then you can do :

```
SELECT *
FOM yourTable
WHERE (expYear > @Y1 OR (expYear = @Y1 AND expMonth >= @M1))
    AND (expYear < @Y2 OR (expYear = @Y2 AND expMonth <= @M2))
```

If your @M1 and @M2 variables values are always separated by one year (12) at most, it is easy to keep only @currentYear (considered as @Y1) parameter as SP input and to compute @Y2 variable from @M1 and @M2 comparison. For example :

```
IF @M2 < @M1
BEGIN
    SET @Y2 = @Y1 + 1;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Y2 = @Y1;
END
```

As an extra info, you should never rely on computation from expYear and expMonth columns within your query (as other answers stated) because il could be highly inefficient due to missing index usage (especially if you expYear/expMonth have been indexed...).